# How to view Macro extended code?

Tags: smart-contract, compilation

I use this command is ok:

```
eosio-cpp hello.cpp -o hello.wasm
```

But I want to view Macro extended code by option `-E - Only run the preprocessor`,

I use this command:

```
eosio-cpp hello.cpp -E
```

And get reponse with error:

```
Running without flags.
/Users/fospring/work/cpp/src/github.com/EOSIO/test_contract/hello/hello.cpp:1:10: fatal error:
      'eosio/eosio.hpp' file not found
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, action <hi> does not have a ricardian contract
1 error generated.
Error while processing /Users/fospring/work/cpp/src/github.com/EOSIO/test_contract/hello/hello.cpp.
abigen error
```